# Codeigniter(HMVC) core classes is not loaded in pre_contoller hook

Tags: codeigniter

I have downloaded the ci-hmvc-master and setup it.
Now in that I have created a one hook at pre_controller hook point.
In that hook, I have created one function that print the current class and method.
my code looks like this:

```
   <?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Authentication{
      protected $CI;

      public function __construct() {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
      } 
      public function is_loggedin(){
        $class = $this->CI->router->fetch_class();
        echo $class;
      }
    }
```

This code is working fine. I got the class name.

Now my issue is that when I use this same code in HMVC which is created from normal MVC (replacing some of the folders and files) then I got the error like:

> Call to a member function fetch_class() on null

Means The pre_controller hook executes before the super object has been fully constructed, so get_instance() can't work.

So, why it is working in HMVC extension which I have downloaded and why it is 
not working in simple HMVC which is created from MVC.

Is there any configuration is missing?

Comment: you should use a ´post_controller` hook, the thing is https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src/f77a3fc9a6fdbfa47d70c921dac31d6d29a664e6/third_party/MX/Ci.php?at=codeigniter-3.x&fileviewer=file-view-default#Ci.php-46 - this gets instantiated before the CI_Controller would instantiate himself - thats why you got the super object

Comment: Yes, I know that using "post_controller" my issue is resolved. but what about if i want to use "pre_controller" ?

Comment: its not possible - because CI Controller gets instantiated by the current controller- and pre controller means its called immediately prior to any of your controllers being called. and sry instead of `post_controller` i meant ofc `post_controller_constructor`...

Comment: Okay...but when i use direct CI(hmvc) extension which is downloaded from git then pre-controller hook works perfectly. So only i want to know that why it is working in that ??

Comment: dude no offense - i posted the reason in my first comment - take a look at this link and you'll see what i mean

Comment: Okay i got the answer. Thank you so much.